# Which of the following allows more than one statement to appear on a single text Line?

Tags: vb.net, line, new-operator

Which of the following allows more than one statement to appear on a single text
Line?

- a) Colon ( : )
- b) Semicolon ( ; )
- c) Space + Underscore ( _ )
- d) Underscore + space ( _ )

Comment: umm... was this a test? You could have figured out in less than 5 minutes yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Basic .NET Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050(VS.71).aspx) shows that a [`StatementTerminator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711981(VS.71).aspx) is either a [`LineTerminator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711640(VS.71).aspx) (which is a newline or a couple of other choices) or a colon (':').

Answer (score 0):

Colon. Space + Underscore is used to split a single statement over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean what allows a single statement to appear on MORE than one line of text, e.g:

somefunction(param1

```
          param2

          param3)
```

If so, the answer is [space][underscore], as:

somefunction(param1 _

```
          param2 _

          param3)
```

Hmmm, just had to edit my reply to show newlines, but could only get it correctly formatted by using 2 newlines, but (formatting aside) you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines:

```
IF Value = 10 THEN
    IncrementCounter
    AnotherValue = 42
    YetAnotherValue = "Hello World!"
    CallOtherFunction 24, 28
ENDIF
```

are equivalent to:

```
IF Value = 10 THEN IncrementCounter: AnotherValue = 42: YetAnotherValue = "Hello World!": CallOtherFunction 24, 28
```

*(Long line causing a scroll bar to appear is intentional.)*

But please don't write code that resembles the second example.